# How to filter base class collection based on a derived class field?

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance

Let's say I have a collection named `MyThings` that holds objects of the class `Thing` and I have a class called `ShinyThing` which is a derived from `Thing`, so I do:

```
MyThings boxWithMyThings = new MyThings();
ShinyThing Diamond = new ShinyThing(){ facets =  10; weight = 500 };
boxWithMyThings.Add(Diamond);
```

How would I filter the collection `boxWithMyThings` using the attributes of the derived class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `OfType` method, as long as `boxWithMyThings` implements `IEnumerable<Thing>`:

```
var filtered = boxWithMyThings.OfType<ShingThing>().Where(st => st.facets == 10);
```

If you want to  filter multiple types (not just `ShinyThings` you can use `Concat` together with many similar calls:

```
IEnumerable<Thing> shinyEnough = boxWithMyThings.OfType<ShingThing>().Where(st => st.shininess >= 10);
IEnumerable<Thing> dirtyEnough = boxWithMyThings.OfType<DirtyThing>().Where(dt => dt.dirtiness >= 10);
var veryDirtyAndVeryCleanObjects = shinyEnough.Concat(dirtyEnough);
```

Of course, you can put all of the `Where` predicates here into one big `Where` clause by checking types and casting, which may be less readable but more efficient:

```
boxWithMyThings.Where(t =>  
     { 
         if (t is ShinyThing) 
                return (t as ShinyThing).shininess >= 10;
         else if (t is DirtyThing) 
                return (t as DirtyThing).dirtiness >= 10; 
         else return false;
     });
```

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you only want ShinyThings? If so, use `OfType`:

```
// I'm assuming MyThings implements IEnumerable<MyThing>
var heavyShinyThings = boxWithMyThings.OfType<ShinyThing>()
                                      .Where(x => x.weight > 100);
```